# Jquery: If form is blank load this query

Tags: php, jquery

I've got some JQuery which monitors a form.  Basically, for every keyup it will call a php file to search the database.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#faq_search_input").watermark("Begin Typing to Search");

    $("#faq_search_input").keyup(function() {
        var faq_search_input = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'keyword='+ faq_search_input;

        if (faq_search_input.length > 2) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "core/functions/searchdata.php",
                data: dataString,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('input#faq_search_input').addClass('loading');
                },
                success: function(server_response) {
                    $('#searchresultdata').empty();
                    $('#searchresultdata').append(server_response);
                    $('span#faq_category_title').html(faq_search_input);
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

This works fine, however it filters the results in `#searchresultdata` depending on the query. The only thing is, if nothing is in the form, I want it to load everything - the user should not have to click the form to do this, therefore a `.blur` would not work.

The PHP file is simply:

```
if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should handle a [*] search on your server

```
$query = "SELECT Image, Manufacturer, Model FROM Device_tbl WHERE Manufacturer LIKE '%$keyword%' OR Model LIKE '%$keyword%";
if ($keyword=='*') $query = "SELECT Image, Manufacturer, Model FROM Device_tbl";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#faq_search_input").watermark("Begin Typing to Search");

    $("#faq_search_input").keyup(function() {
        var faq_search_input = $(this).val();
        if (faq_search_input =='') faq_search_input ='*';
        var dataString = 'keyword='+ faq_search_input;

        if (faq_search_input.length > 2 || faq_search_input=='*') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "core/functions/searchdata.php",
                data: dataString,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('input#faq_search_input').addClass('loading');
                },
                success: function(server_response) {
                    $('#searchresultdata').empty();
                    $('#searchresultdata').append(server_response);
                    $('span#faq_category_title').html(faq_search_input);
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
    $("#faq_search_input").trigger('keyup');
});
```

Comment: I think I understand this.  Basically its just saying if "keyword" is blank, then put a * in.  The only issue is that my query is:

**bold**SELECT Image, Manufacturer, Model FROM Device_tbl WHERE Manufacturer LIKE '%$keyword%' OR Model LIKE '%$keyword%'**bold**

Therefore, the search results are blank

Comment: Great thanks, however is there a way to force it on page load? That way all results are shown on load.  I guess its just some JS to submit the form on load

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading *all* results initially, then could you not just store this in a JavaScript array and filter the results with JavaScript? This would save you a HTTP request on every key press, which can only be good for speed and resource usage of your site.

EDIT: Sample.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT `title` FROM `your_table`";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $rows[] = $row['title'];
    }
    echo '<script>var data = ' . json_encode($rows) . ';</script>';
?>
<form method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="faq_search_input" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
    // I presume you're using jQuery
    var searchInput = $('#faq_search_input');
    var searchResults = $('#searchresultdata');
    var tmpArray = data;

    // add all results to results div
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        searchResults.append('<li>' + val + '</li>');
    });

    searchInput.attr('placeholder', 'Begin typing to search');
    searchInput.keyup(function() {
        // hide any <li> in your #searchresultdata that don't match input
    });
</script>
```

I don't know what is in your `serverresponse` variable, so I can only guess what gets put into the `searchresultdata` `<div>`. You'll also need to modify the SQL query to match your table and column names.

**Contents of searchdata.php**

```
$query = "SELECT Image, Manufacturer, Model FROM Device_tbl WHERE Manufacturer LIKE '%$keyword%' OR Model LIKE '%$keyword%'";
if ($keyword=='*') $query = "SELECT Image, Manufacturer, Model FROM Device_tbl";
$result=mysql_query($query, $database_connection) or die(mysql_error());

if($result){
    if(mysql_affected_rows($database_connection)!=0){
          while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
?>
     <div class="hold-cont">
        <div class="holder">
            <div class="image-hold" >
                <img class="image-icon" src="<? echo $deviceimg.($row->Image); ?>"/>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-name devicename-txt"><? echo($row->Manufacturer. ' ' .$row->Model);  ?></div>
    </div>
     <?
    }
    }else {
        echo 'No Results for :"'.$_GET['keyword'].'"';
    }

}
}else {
    echo 'Parameter Missing';
}
```

Comment: Possible definitely as there could be over 500 records.  Just need to figure out how to do this, however im just trying to get it working first  Then optimise it?

Comment: Personally, if there's over 500 records and you want to filter as the user types, then that's going to be a lot of HTTP requests and database calls. Hardly optimal.

Comment: What do you suggestion the best way to handle this would be if I want realtime searching as above too?

Comment: As above: do a `SELECT` and fetch all the records, store them in a JavaScript array, and filter the results with JavaScript on each key-press. Only one HTTP request and only one database call.

Comment: I've added in the contents of searchdata.php.  It just queries the database using the keyword and outputs the results into a layout.  Im just struggling to make heads or tails of how to implement your additions

Comment: I've tried your code but I am getting Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: My code wasn't a working solution; more a sketch to get you started.